# Prove that the $24\Big\lfloor\frac{p+3}{6}\Big\rfloor p+1=n^2$ for any prime p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Have met an experimental result, that for any prime p:

$$24\Big\lfloor\frac{p+3}{6}\Big\rfloor p+1=n^2$$

Where
$$n \equiv\pm 1\pmod {12}$$

The last rule is true for any solution of the first equation even for nonprime $p$.

I was trying to prove this using possible forms of primes such as $p\equiv 1,3,5,7,11\pmod {12}$. But either I am doing something wrong or this is not the right way can not reach the final result.

Comment: For the prime $p=3$ I get $24\cdot 1 \cdot 3+1=73$ which is not a square.

Comment: thanks,  3 is the only exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $p = 6k+1$, then your expression is just:

$$24\cdot k\cdot(6k+1) + 1 = 144k^2+24k+1 = (12k+1)^2.$$
You can do a similar thing for when $p = 6k-1$ and the only other possibility is $p = 2.$

Comment: So we can say that this is true for any number of form $p=6k \pm 1$. Nice answer.